# MS SQL Obfuscation of Varchar(10) to Integer and back?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a two fields that identify a user, one being a Integer and one being a varchar(10) in the format of 'AA111X' where the first two are alpha and the final x is alphanumeric, and need to convert that into an integer for the integer field as a translation. The integer value used to be provided for us but is no longer. The answer may well be this isn't possible, and a lookup table will have to be used but I'm trying to avoid the schema change if possible.

Comment: As a note, I know I can always encrypt/decrypt the varchar(10) field but I need to end up with a value that fits within the integer field if possible

Comment: Is the '111' part of 'AA111X' always a unique identifier? If so, just strip out the alpha characters and convert to int. If not, just do an alpha transform to a two digit integer. You don't specify what the limits of the alphanumeric field is (length) so no idea if that would fit in an integer or not.

Comment: `CAST(CAST(YourField AS binary(6)) AS int)` maybe?

Comment: on the alpha portion is currently (and forever likely) 2 characters, the numeric portion is always 3 characters and the trailing character is most often a number but can be an alpha character. essentially all values are unique from each other.

For instance You can have a value of 'AA1234' and 'AA123A' but not two 'AA1234' if that makes sense

Comment: @Charlieface: an `INT` only holds 32 bits; `BINARY(6)` is right out. That said, the total range (assuming the description is accurate) would fit, since there are only 26 * 26 * 10 * 10 * 10 * 36  = 24336000 unique values (assuming a single case, and 6 symbols for all identifiers). Finding a succinct T-SQL expression for such a translation is another matter, though.

Comment: @JeroenMostert You're right, I meant `bigint`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it necessary that you actually treat the first two characters as some value base 26, and the last character as some value base 36? Or is it only necessary that you can generate a unique integer for any possible input, in a way that can be converted back if necessary?

If the latter, and if the existing values are considered case insensitive, this solution will always result in a value that fits in a 4 byte integer:

```
declare @val varchar(10) = 'zz111z';

select cast(
         concat(
            ascii(substring(val, 1, 1)),
            ascii(substring(val, 2, 1)),
            substring(val, 3, 3),
            ascii(substring(val, 6, 1))
         )
         as int
       )
from   (select upper(@val)) v(val);
```

Comment: thanks Allmhuran, that's very similar to what I was writing already and it got me the rest of the way through. simply used char(substring(cast(90 as varchar),1,2)) etc to get back to the upper cased characters as case sensitivity is unimportant in this case

Comment: Roger. If you do need to be able to get back to the exact original character representation, including case, you could append a `- 30` to each of the `ascii(...)` expressions in the `concat`, and then add 30 back to the integer "fragments" before turning them back into `char`. This keeps all the alpha/alphanumeric elements 2 digits long in the int result of the first conversion, making it easy to parse them back out when converting back. Let me know if that's not clear and I'll add the whole thing to my answer.